# Why CellValueNedded is called for all array list items initially

Tags: c#

I implemented code for `datagridview` in `virtualmode`. My store contains 42 items in `array`. Can anyone explains me why initially it calls CellValueNeeded 42 times and then 13 times? I do understand 13 times because that's items which can be shown on grid in real time but i do not uunderstand that 42 times before. If i would have million items in array `CellValueNeeded` would be also called milion times initially which makes no sense to me as those records are not required at that point but 13 and from my perspective it should be not what virtualmode is made for.

[The code was taken from MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control)

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewVirtual
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // Declare an ArrayList to serve as the data store.
        private System.Collections.ArrayList customers =
            new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        // Declare a Customer object to store data for a row being edited.
        private Customer customerInEdit;

        // Declare a variable to store the index of a row being edited.
        // A value of -1 indicates that there is no row currently in edit.
        private int rowInEdit = -1;

        // Declare a variable to indicate the commit scope.
        // Set this value to false to use cell-level commit scope.
        private bool rowScopeCommit = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
            this.Text = "DataGridView virtual-mode demo (row-level commit scope)";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Enable virtual mode.
            this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;

            // Connect the virtual-mode events to event handlers.
            this.dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += new
                DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded);
            this.dataGridView1.CellValuePushed += new
                DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValuePushed);
            this.dataGridView1.NewRowNeeded += new
                DataGridViewRowEventHandler(dataGridView1_NewRowNeeded);
            this.dataGridView1.RowValidated += new
                DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowValidated);
            this.dataGridView1.RowDirtyStateNeeded += new
                QuestionEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowDirtyStateNeeded);
            this.dataGridView1.CancelRowEdit += new
                QuestionEventHandler(dataGridView1_CancelRowEdit);
            this.dataGridView1.UserDeletingRow += new
                DataGridViewRowCancelEventHandler(dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow);

            // Add columns to the DataGridView.
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn companyNameColumn = new
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            companyNameColumn.HeaderText = "Company Name";
            companyNameColumn.Name = "Company Name";
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn contactNameColumn = new
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            contactNameColumn.HeaderText = "Contact Name";
            contactNameColumn.Name = "Contact Name";
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(companyNameColumn);
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(contactNameColumn);
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode =
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

            // Add some sample entries to the data store.
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "1", "1"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "2", "2"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "3", "3"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "4", "4"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "5", "5"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "6", "6"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "7", "7"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "8", "8"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "9", "9"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "10", "10"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "11", "11"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "12", "12"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "13", "13"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "14", "14"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "15", "15"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "16", "16"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "17", "17"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "18", "18"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "19", "19"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "20", "20"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "21", "21"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "22", "22"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "23", "23"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "24", "24"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "25", "25"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "26", "26"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "27", "27"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "28", "28"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "29", "29"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "30", "30"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "31", "31"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "32", "32"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "33", "33"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "34", "34"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "35", "35"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "36", "36"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "37", "37"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "38", "38"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "39", "39"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "40", "40"));
            this.customers.Add(new Customer(
                "41", "42"));


            // Set the row count, including the row for new records.
            this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 42;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {


            listBox1.Items.Add($"dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded RowIndex {e.RowIndex}");
            // If this is the row for new records, no values are needed.
            if (e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) return;

            Customer customerTmp = null;

            // Store a reference to the Customer object for the row being painted.
            if (e.RowIndex == rowInEdit)
            {
                customerTmp = this.customerInEdit;
            }
            else
            {
                customerTmp = (Customer)this.customers[e.RowIndex];
            }

            // Set the cell value to paint using the Customer object retrieved.
            switch (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case "Company Name":
                    e.Value = customerTmp.CompanyName;
                    break;

                case "Contact Name":
                    e.Value = customerTmp.ContactName;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellValuePushed(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customerTmp = null;

            // Store a reference to the Customer object for the row being edited.
            if (e.RowIndex < this.customers.Count)
            {
                // If the user is editing a new row, create a new Customer object.
                this.customerInEdit ??= new Customer(
                    ((Customer)this.customers[e.RowIndex]).CompanyName,
                    ((Customer)this.customers[e.RowIndex]).ContactName);
                customerTmp = this.customerInEdit;
                this.rowInEdit = e.RowIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                customerTmp = this.customerInEdit;
            }

            // Set the appropriate Customer property to the cell value entered.
            String newValue = e.Value as String;
            switch (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case "Company Name":
                    customerTmp.CompanyName = newValue;
                    break;

                case "Contact Name":
                    customerTmp.ContactName = newValue;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_NewRowNeeded(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new Customer object when the user edits
            // the row for new records.
            this.customerInEdit = new Customer();
            this.rowInEdit = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Save row changes if any were made and release the edited
            // Customer object if there is one.
            if (e.RowIndex >= this.customers.Count &&
                e.RowIndex != this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                // Add the new Customer object to the data store.
                this.customers.Add(this.customerInEdit);
                this.customerInEdit = null;
                this.rowInEdit = -1;
            }
            else if (this.customerInEdit != null &&
                     e.RowIndex < this.customers.Count)
            {
                // Save the modified Customer object in the data store.
                this.customers[e.RowIndex] = this.customerInEdit;
                this.customerInEdit = null;
                this.rowInEdit = -1;
            }
            else if (this.dataGridView1.ContainsFocus)
            {
                this.customerInEdit = null;
                this.rowInEdit = -1;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_RowDirtyStateNeeded(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.QuestionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!rowScopeCommit)
            {
                // In cell-level commit scope, indicate whether the value
                // of the current cell has been modified.
                e.Response = this.dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CancelRowEdit(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.QuestionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.rowInEdit == this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 &&
                this.rowInEdit == this.customers.Count)
            {
                // If the user has canceled the edit of a newly created row,
                // replace the corresponding Customer object with a new, empty one.
                this.customerInEdit = new Customer();
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user has canceled the edit of an existing row,
                // release the corresponding Customer object.
                this.customerInEdit = null;
                this.rowInEdit = -1;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender,
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.Index < this.customers.Count)
            {
                // If the user has deleted an existing row, remove the
                // corresponding Customer object from the data store.
                this.customers.RemoveAt(e.Row.Index);
            }

            if (e.Row.Index == this.rowInEdit)
            {
                // If the user has deleted a newly created row, release
                // the corresponding Customer object.
                this.rowInEdit = -1;
                this.customerInEdit = null;
            }
        }

        private void btnClearLb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is you data coming from?  Normally when I put data into a DGV is first put the data into a datatable.  Then simply use datagridview1.DataSource = dt.  This one line replaces all the code in the link.  If you have a database like SQL Server then fill the datatable using a Data Adapter.

Comment: @jdweng this is implementatiin of virtual Mode. Link comming from msdn and data if you look more close stores in array in provided code as mentioned

Comment: No.  The data is hard coded in the code.  The virtual mode is just the structure of the customer.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, data is hardcoded. Can you answer the question?

Comment: The code is just an example of how to use the DGV.  As part of the example hard coded data was added.  If a real application the data will come from a file or database.  The hard coded values are in the load event. Putting in the load makes sense if the data is always fixed like coming from a file.  In other cases the data may be dynamic and will be added after the load method.

Comment: @jdweng i know production data would come from either db or file but what diffrence does it takes to my question? The data is loaded from some where, The question is why initially it calls cellvalueneeded 42 Times So the count of data store and then the Real view count. I dont understand first behaviour and thats my question.

Comment: It is just 42 rows of test data.  A real application would not add the test data.